# quickblox chat sample is showing errors

Tags: android, sdk, quickblox

hello I try to implement open group chat feature in my android app by using quickblox android sdk

I import the sample chat from quickblox android sdk and import the core and chat jars as external jars through properties-> java build path-> library

and pull-to-refresh as a library through properties-> android-> add

I followed all the steps in quickblox docs

but still I get errors in splashactivity project

it shows error as R cannot be resolved to a variable. ........

a spend whole day but i did't get anything please could someone help me

Answer (score 0):

I would put this as a comment but don't have enough reputation yet.  Errors in your XML layouts can lead to this error (R does not get built if there are errors in the layouts), so check there first.  If everything is good there, check your imports in the file you have the errors in.  You might have a bad import; you should have something like:

```
import <package_name>.R;
```

If that is not referencing your current project you will have a problem.

Also, make sure you do a Project > Clean.